# java servlet Filter : What is the best practice in checking Privileges of Users?

Tags: jsp, authorization, servlet-filters

I have a Filter that propagates the user's credentials down the stack using a ThreadLocal. I want to reuse the same filter for Authorization purposes as well.

Let's say that the webapp(ajax) has about 100 JSPs and part of the application is developed using plain JSPs and the remaining part using Spring MVC 3(with controllers and JSPs). If the request is coming for a .JSP or a Spring MVC Controlled resource, my 1st thoughts were

1. to put a list of JSPs( and spring MVC resources) that actually need Authorization and then
2. to check if the user's role has the right privileges for accessing that resource(or JSP).

If the app had 100s of such resources to check for, it doesn't make sense to put all the JSP names in the Filter (that would be a maintenance nightmare as well). If I were to move the list of all the JSPs to a property file and corresponding list of all the privileges required for that resource(JSP), then I could loop through the JSPs and check if the user has one of the required privileges.

does the plan make sense? How have people implemented Authorization of JSP/resources at the server?

Answer (score 1):

I would let [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) do all the heavy lifting rather than using a hand-crafted solution.  Check out the [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html).